# HTML: how to adjust width of disabled INPUT

Tags: html, css, input

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="some size" disabled="true/false">
```

Form allows me to provide up to 35 characters long ID, which is read-only in edit mode (its rendered as disabled in such a case). How can I determine its width depending on text length? I want to be able to display the field wide enough so that whole text shows off. Tried it with size attribute but it is preety much useless, because it doesn't take font width into account.
Like its to narrow for:

wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxxx

and too wide for:

iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii

any help will be appreciated

Comment: does this have anything to do with the fact that the control is disabled?

Comment: Do you want to dinamically vary the size of the text input box as the length of the text it holds increases??

Comment: @Andreas - not directly, its just assured that the component remains the same

Comment: I usually use `span` styled as `input` in this case,

Comment: @Harikrishnan - not dinamically, I know what is the text length, I want to render input text that accomodates it.

Comment: @Saram - I also tried it. But firefox allows to set a focus on span (as well as div) - which was the root for the change. When I click on such a span/div a prompt shows and it looks like it is possible to type a text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the width of each letter to be taken into account then you could just use a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Monospaced fonts have all characters at equal width:

```css
input[type="text"] {
    font-family:monospace;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/q7NRb/

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="some size" disabled="true/false" onkeypress="Adjustwidth(this);">
```

you have to adjust the width of your control with the help of some javascript like...

```
function Adjustwidth(obj)
{
     obj.style.width = ((obj.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Looks like a scientific algorithm :)

Comment: **oninput** is better than **onkeypress** because it allows backspace.

Answer (score 1):

You could have something like this

```
<input id="txt" type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 8) + 'px';">
```

Also adding the Mono-space font will take care of the trailing whitespace

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AUgtS/)

Comment: For **readonly** input you can use onfocus and autofocus. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AUgtS/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the input's width to adjust the size of its contents then you'll have to do some js. An option is to create a temporary span with identical styling, fill it with the same text and measure its size:

```
 function UpdateWidth() {
        var input = $('#yourInputId');
        $('<span id="width">').append( input.val() ).appendTo('body');
        input.width( $('#width').width() + 1 );
        $('#width').remove();
    }
```

Note, that you have to ensure that the span has the same styling (font and etc).